# Sequelize is chopping of nested key length

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have a model named `ManufacturerGuideline` which is nested at the 4th level. When I try to fetch the record, its chopping of `ManufacturerGuideline` keys length to 5 characters. Although the Key value stored in postgreSQL table has full length.

**Routes:**

```
router.get('/:manufacturer_id', function(req, res) {
  var manufacturer_id = req.params.manufacturer_id;
  models.Manufacturer.findAll({
    where: {
      id: manufacturer_id
    },
    order: [[models.ManufacturerTab, 'sequence', 'ASC']],
    include: [{
                model: models.ManufacturerTab, 
                include: [{
                  model: models.ManufacturerField, 
                  include: [models.ManufacturerGuideline]
              }]
            }
        ]
  }).
  then(function(manufacturers) {  
      res.status(200).json(manufacturers);  
  }, function(error) {  
     res.status(500).send(error);  
  });  
});
```

So if the column name is `Manufacturer` it displays as `Manuf`. This issue is only appearing with `ManufacturerGuideline` table and not with the parent associated table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was finally able to fix the issue by specifying `separate: true` while including the model in the routes.

```
include: [{
  separate: true,
  model: models.ManufacturerGuideline
}]
```

Comment: Only supported for hasMany associations

https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll

Comment: Any reason why this is necessary to add? What is the necessity to Sequelize clipping the key name for nested joins like this one?